# Getting a Javascript POPUP window to work when clicking on READ MORE

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I found this nice POPUP window code which works very smoothly. With the help of Stackoverflow I was able to put together some code to cutoff long strings, so words are not broken in the middle.  Both pieces of code work great.

When I trigger the "p" element which encloses an "a" anchor with an ID=”showshort” to call the string limiting code that code works fine displaying the shortened string, but the popup is no longer triggered when clicking on “Read more”.  If I do not trigger the string limiting code with ID="showshort" the popup window works great.

The script:

```
 <script language="javascript">
  /* popup box code */
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.popup').click(function() {
  var popupid = $(this).attr('rel');
  $('#' + popupid).fadeIn();
  $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
  $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=60)'}).fadeIn();

  var popuptopmargin = ($('#' + popupid).height() + 10) / 2;
  var popupleftmargin = ($('#' + popupid).width() + 10) / 2;
  $('#' + popupid).css({
  'margin-top' : -popuptopmargin,
  'margin-left' : -popupleftmargin
  });
  });
  $('#fade').click(function() {
  $('#fade , #popuprel , #popuprel2 , #popuprel3').fadeOut()
  return false;
  });
  });

  /* code to shorten text intelligently */
    $(function(){
        var $elem = $('.shorten');      // The element or elements with the text to hide
        var $limit = 100;       // The number of characters to show
        var $str = $elem.html();    // Getting the text
        var $strtemp = $str.substr(0,$limit);   // Get the visible part of the string
            var $str = $strtemp.substr(0, Math.min($strtemp.length, $strtemp.lastIndexOf(" ")))
            $str = $str + '<a href="#" rel="popuprel" class="popup"><br><br>Read more...</a>';
    document.getElementById('showshort').innerHTML = $str;
    })
</script>
```

The style

```
<style>
/* necessary for popup box js*/
#trigger {
text-align:center;
} 

/* necessary for popup box js */
#fade { 
display: none;  /* Hidden as default */ 
background: #000;
position: fixed;
left: 0; top: 0;
width: 100%; height: 100%;
opacity: .60;
z-index: 9999;
}
/* affects placement of closing "X" on popup box*/
.closeX {
position:absolute;
left: 95%;
top: 2%;
} 
.popupbox {
width:633px;
height:300px;
overflow: auto;
background-color:#FFF0F0;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
display: none; /* Hidden as default */
float: left;
border-radius: 10px;
position: fixed;
top: 50%; left: 50%;
z-index: 99999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
z-index:999999;
}
</style>
```

and the HTML

```
<body>
<p id="showshor">Some short text...<a href="#" rel="popuprel" class="popup"><br><br>Read more...</a></p>

<div class="popupbox shorten" id="popuprel">
<p>This is text inside popup.This is text inside popup.This is text inside popup.
This is text inside popup.This is text inside popup.This is text inside popup.
This is text inside popup.This is text inside popup.This is text inside popup.
This is text inside popup.This is text inside popup.This is text inside popup.
This is text inside popup.This is text inside popup.This is text inside popup.</p> 
<!-- Closing "X" -->
<a class="closeX" href="javascript:window.location.href='#'"><img src="close_pop.png" width="20px" height="20px"/></a>
</div> <!-- popupbox -->
</body>
</html>
```

Right now the ID of the "p" element is purposely misspelled.  With it this way the popup window works perfectly.  Change the ID to properly spell "showshort" to call the string shortening code and the shortening code works perfectly returning the shortened string with the exact same "p" inner code shown above in the body now, but when I click "Read more..." nothing happens -- no popup.

http://jsfiddle.net/32sAB/1/

Comment: please put on a working jsfiddle demo and non-working demo that will make it easier to understand you

Comment: OK, I’ve put it on “jsfiddle”.   Run it as is and you will see there is no shortened text from the DIV because ID=“showshort” is intentionally misspelled so nothing inside the first <p> element is disturded.  Only the word “Some…” appears, as it should and if you click on “Read more” you will see the popup work.  Now change the ID=”showshort” so it is spelled correctly so the text in the <p> element is replaced with the shortened string from the DIV and run it again.  This time you will see the shortened string from the DIV, but the “Read more” no longer activates the popup window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JavaScript, I think you have two $(document).ready ($(function) is a shortcut I believe). Since $(document).ready is before your $(function), $(document).ready gets run first.

Basically, you set your onclick event handler for the a element in $(document).ready, then in $(function), you overwrite the entire content of showshort, which replaces the a element with a new one that lacks the onclick event handler.

Perhaps, when you want to append text, you should use an element's insertBefore method, so that its existing child elements don't get overwritten.

Edit: see fiddle in comment.

Comment: I'm new to Javascript.  I think I follow what you are saying and it sounds right.  However, I'm not knowledgeable enough to use the "insertBefore" method.  I just read up on it and the examples show how to insert another element before an inner element, but I'm not sure how to use it just to replace the text for the <p> element so I don't disturb the <a> anchor which contains the clicbable event.  An examaple would be helpful.

Comment: Since you have given me this clue, I've tried three different methods to replace the string while preserving the click event and none of them have worked.  I tried these two:                     var $e = $('#showshort');
$e.html($e.html().replace("Some...", "Other"));

Comment: Actually, after looking at your code more closely, I don't think you need to append any texts (unless I am misunderstanding something). Here's a fiddle to your code, modified and commented: http://jsfiddle.net/LsZnA/

Comment: I updated the fiddle to make your close button work: http://jsfiddle.net/LsZnA/1/

Comment: Perhaps you should check out jQuery UI's dialog widget. It's probably a lot easier than creating a popup dialog from scratch. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Are you kidding.  I'm not even close to creating something from scratch.  I got this code from a site another programmer used.  Naturally, I've read about JQuery UI, but I haven't even delved into that yet.  I haven't a clue what it's about.

Comment: My mistake.  I didn't explain what I was trying to do very well.  I'm trying to display the shortened string in the normal browser window and when you click "Read more..." the popup comes up with the entire text, not the shorter string.  Like for an article where you click "Read more" to read the whole article.

Comment: Thanks so much.  These are all just exercises to help me learn, plus I'm trying to build a toolbox for future efforts.  I'll download the code and study it.  Hopefully, I'll understand what's going on.

Comment: One last comment – after copying your code from “jsfiddle” into my document it wouldn’t run.  I copied it back into a blank “jsfiddle” to make sure I didn’t copy wrong, but it worked beautifully.  So I searched more on the internet and apparently, because “jsfiddle” defaults to (onload) this causes “jsfiddle” to wrap all javascript in a $( document ).ready() statement.  Once I did that it all worked beautifully.  Again, thanks a million Hans.